# Why use an interface for CONSTANTs?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, constants

So, while doing some project, I found that some Java libraries use Interfaces for Constants. For e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html

That made me wonder why would anyone do that? Why not just a class? What's its advantage. To me, it looks like an anti-pattern.

Comment: It *is* an anti-pattern. (I don't know why they did it though. Probably just because they could and they hadn't discovered it was bad yet)

Comment: Because they didn't have enums back then when it was created.

Comment: This was before the day you could do `static import` or powerful, auto-completing IDEs, so they could then `implement` those `interfaces` and it would lessen the amount of typing you would have to.  What would the benefits of using a `Class` that only only contained `static final`'s in it be?  You really don't want to instantiate the class do you?  Make it `abstract`? But where's the benefit? It's also a work-around for the fact that everything (primitives excluded) MUST be an Object (or `interface`)

Answer (score -1):

A lot of the swing code is from many versions ago and has not been updated to use more recent features for backward compatibility reasons. In this case an `enum` would be more appropriate.